# How do I iterate on a JSON file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, iteration

I have this issue. I want to iterate through the attributes of a JSON structure, i.e this structure

```
var txt = '{"employees":{' +
'"p1":{'+
    '"info":{'+
        '"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" }},' +
'"p2":{'+
    '"info":{'+
        '"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" }},' +
'"p3":{'+
    '"info":{'+
        '"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }}'+

'}}';
```

I dont want to do something like

> json.employees.p1.info.firstName;

(using the p1) I want to do something like

```
for(var i = 0; i<3;++i){
    console.log(json.employees.p[i].info.firstName);
}
```

Does someone know how to do it?

I want to do that because the attribute p can be N not so I can't do p1, p2, p3, p4, ..., p101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access properties of JavaScript objects using **bracket notation**.
It is useful when you have to define property name using variable or expression.

So. for your situation, you could access the properties of `employees` like this:

```
json.employees['p'+(i+1)].info.firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate objects like so:

```
for (var k in your_object)
    console.log(your_object[k]);
```

So in your case, to iterate through all P objects:

```
for (var k in json.employees)
    console.log(json.employees[k]);
```